# Expand height of PSD without overflowing other view

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, interface-design, crop

I'm designing a landing page :

[image]

But as I started my background images are too big so when I crop the view downside, I get this:

[image]

How do I make the first section to not overflow its background images on the next section?

Answer (score 1):

I used to do this way (If I understood you correctly:))

1. Place a rectangular shape with the desired size
2. Put the background picture layer on top of the rectangle
3. Create a clipping mask (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Left Mouse CLick</kbd> between the two layers)

[image]

Then you can crop and the picture will not overflow to the picture below

Answer (score 0):

1. Select All. This will make a selection the same size as your canvas.
2. With the background image selected in the layers panel, hit the layer mask button at the bottom of the layers panel.

   Your background image is now masked to the size of the canvas.
3. Resize your canvas.

Comment: Looking again I'm not sure I completely understood your question.. If not, let me know and I will delete my answer!

Comment: I don't need the canvas to fit the image, I need the bigger images fit into the canvas (without overflowing) ... But I want to expand my canvas downside to make another section of the website and I don't want the first section (which I have now) to overflow the second one (which I want to make)

Comment: Ok... That's what I explained how to do, mask the image to the size of the canvas (before resizing the canvas) so your image doesn't overflow in to what will be the second section

Comment: I masked it  but the image resizes anyway ... I want the image placed how I want.

Comment: Then it isn't masked...

Comment: Look it is masked : http://image.prntscr.com/image/a70aab78afe4413e976024ac714a63d1.png


And look the image resizes :( : http://image.prntscr.com/image/a1f6571ddc3d4b2b9b7b64e5207b22e1.png

Comment: Isn't that another image behind? It's hard to tell whats going on without seeing the layers too. And isn't that a transform and not crop?

Comment: Either way, a mask won't get affected by a canvas size change

Answer (score 0):

I just made a new file and placed the .psd there.

The downside is that I can't edit the section because it links to the original file.

http://image.prntscr.com/image/ca2659749e2f4f359643f53eb23bd503.png

Comment: You can double click the smart object to edit its contents

Comment: yeah... But I'd like to edit it in the same tab, I mean I don't want a smart object.